Adding Configure button to a custom chart
I am creating a custom chart in Azure DevOps dashboard using extensions, however I am unable to figure out how to add "Configure" button onto the widget under the three dots to customize any functionality of the widget. My current js and html code is below.
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="sdk/scripts/VSS.SDK.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="widget">
        <h2 class="title">Salman Widget</h2>
        <div id="Chart-Container"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "vss-web-extension-sdk": "^5.141.0"
  }
}

vss-extension.json
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "my-chart",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "name": "Test By Salman",
    "description": "Just a Test",
    "publisher": "TTT",
    "categories": [
        "Azure Boards",
        "Azure Pipelines",
        "Azure Test Plans"
    ],
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "icons": {
        "default": "img/logo.png"
    },
    "demands": ["contribution/ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-sdk-version-2", "contribution/ms.vss-web.charts-service"],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "chart",
            "type": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-catalog"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Testing",
                "description": "A simple chart widget with no configuration and hard-coded data.",
                "catalogIconUrl": "img/CatalogIcon.png",
                "uri": "chart.html",
                "supportedSizes": [
                    {
                        "rowSpan": 3,
                        "columnSpan": 3
                    }
                ],
                "supportedScopes": [
                    "project_team"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "chart.html",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "sdk/scripts/VSS.SDK.js",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "img",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "scripts",
            "addressable": true
        }
    ],
    "scopes": [
    ],
    "baseUri": "https://localhost:3000"
}

chart.js
VSS.init({
    explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
    usePlatformStyles: true 
});

VSS.require([
    "TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", 
    "Charts/Services"
    ],
    function (WidgetHelpers, Services) {
    WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
    VSS.register("chart", function () { 
         return {
         load:function() {
            return Services.ChartsService.getService().then(function(chartService){
                var $container = $('#Chart-Container');
                var chartOptions = { 
                    "hostOptions": { 
                        "height": "290", 
                        "width": "300"
                    },
                    "chartType": "column",
                    "series": [{
                        "data": [11, 4, 3, 1]
                    }],
                    "xAxis": { 
                        "labelValues": ["Design", "On Deck", "Completed", "Development"] 
                    }, 
                    "specializedOptions": {
                        "showLabels": "true",
                        "size": 200
                    } 
                };

                chartService.createChart($container, chartOptions);
                return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
            });
            }
         }
        });
VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
});

